# How would you confirm that a colorless liquid given to you is pure water?

Tags: water

How would you confirm that a colorless liquid given to you is pure water?
A very easy solution is to take a sample of colourless liquid and put on stove if it starts boiling exactly at 100 ºC then it is pure water. Any other colourless liquid such as vinegar always have different boiling point. Also observe carefully that after some time whole liquid will convert into vapour without leaving any residue.
Now are there any other ways to understand?

Comment: I'm afraid there's too much of them. Analytic chemistry as a whole is dedicated to things like that.

Comment: BP would only be a crude indication of purity. A measurement of 100 ºC is only good to 1% relative. It is easy to measure ppm levels of chemicals in water. So you'd need to measure BP to 100.0000 ºC. With that sort of precision a correction for the ambient atmospheric pressure would be needed.

Comment: Take a drop, dissolve it in $\ce{CD3OD}$, walk to your closest NMR spectrometer and record a spectrum.

Answer (score 5):

Measurement of [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colligative_properties) like freezing point and boiling point would give you a quick, qualitative though likely correct, answer.  The simplest to do is the measurement of the liquid's freezing point.

If you can, partially freeze your solution in a kitchen freezer, stir well, then measure the temperature while stirring.  Since the freezing point of water is relatively insensitive to atmospheric pressure, you don't have to worry about correcting for the elevation where you live.  This method is commonly used as a quick way to check the [calibration of a thermometer](http://www.vldhealth.org/pdf/environmentalpdf/calibrateeng.pdf).  Of course a measurement of ${0 ^oC}$ would mean that you likely have water.  If it doesn't freeze, assuming your freezer is cold enough to freeze water, then it's not water.  If this is what you observe, drop a small ice crystal or a grain of salt into the solution to initiate ice formation just to be sure it is not [supercooled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercooling).  Also, if it doesn't freeze, measure the temperature of the solution to be sure it is at least several degrees below ${0 ^oC}$.

A shortcut, or as a further check, if you have plenty solution to spare you could take a portion and add enough crushed ice that it doesn't all melt upon stirring.  If you get the same value (${0 ^oC}$) as in the first experiment, you can be pretty confident that your solution is water.  If it were some mixture of solutions with a freezing point of ${0 ^oC}$ (unlikely), this test would give you a different measurement than in the first test due to either [colligative properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colligative_properties) if the amount of ice is small relative to the whole solution or by creating a new, bulk solution with a different melting point than the original solution.

If both of these experiments give you the same result of ${0 ^oC}$, I'll bet my house that it's water.

Answer (score 3):

You could measure various physical properties of the unknown liquid and compare the results to literature values for pure water or to measurements of a known sample of pure water.

However, as a quick and simple test, you could just carefully add pure water with the same temperature to your unknown liquid. If you observe mixing boundaries (schlieren patterns) or even two phases, a change in temperature, or any chemical reaction, your unknown liquid is not pure water.